# Is $|z^2 + 1| > |z|^2 - 1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I am often confused while using complex number formula involving comparisons.

It is known that $|z^2 - a^2| > |z|^2 - a^2$. But is $|z^2 + 1| > |z|^2 - 1$?

Where $z$ is a complex number.

Also, please suggest some proofs so that it is easy to remember such formulae.

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality? This is an immediate consequence. (In both cases, you need to replace $>$ with $\geq$, by the way.)

Comment: Strict inequality is false. $z=i$ results in "$0\gt0$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall $|a+b | \leq |a| + |b| $, the famous triangle inequality. WE have

$$ |z|^2 = |z^2+1-1| \leq |z^2 +1 | + |-1| = |z^2 + 1 | + 1 $$

Answer (score 4):

By the triangle inequality
$$|z^2+1|+1=|z^2+1|+|-1|\geq|z^2+1-1|=|z|^2.$$
The equality occurs for $z=i$.

By the way, $$|z^2+1|>|z|^2-1$$ is wrong for $z=i$.

Comment: Change $z=i$ to $z=\pm i$?

Comment: @Barry, $z=i$ it's enough.

Comment: Agreed, a single counterexample suffices. But it seems simple enough here to include both.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $$ |a - b| \geq ||a|-|b||$$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. (Or any $a, b\in V$ a normed vector space.) This is the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).  Intuitively, if you have vectors of fixed length, the way to make their difference as small as possible is to point them in the same direction.

Substituting $-b$ for $b$ also gives $|a + b| \geq ||a| - |b|| \geq |a| - |b|$.  Now make the appropriate substitutions for your problem and you are done.